# selenium standalone server log console is blank

Tags: selenium

**My problem is:** selenium standalone server log console shows blank

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Install selenium standalone-2.25.0.jar
2. Have test suites in same folder
3. Put in command to run the test through console

`java -jar <location_of_selenium>/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -htmlSuite *firefox <website URL> <location_of_selenium>/Test_suite1/Test_suite1_ts <location_of_selenium>/Test_suite1_results.html`

**Expected output:**
There are errors in my test and it should show in the Selenium log console as well as create a log file in my selenium folder.

**Platform and other Details:**

Selenium version: 2.25.0

OS: Ubuntu

Browser: FireFox

Browser version: 7

Answer (score 0):

1. Test suite names need to have `.html` extension in order for the logs to work

   - side note: for selenium to run all your tests and not just 1, you must add `.html` to your test case files as well.

SOLUTION: Rename the suite file to `Test_suite1_ts.html`

Answer (score 0):

Pls look how this problem I solved:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://libo.ru/ c:\temp\selenium\juzsay\testSute1.html testresult1.html

where:

website URL = http://libo.ru/
location_of_selenium = C:\temp\selenium\juzsay\testSute1.html (build with Selenium IDE) 
location_of_selenium = testresult1.html (file with test result, in selenium-server-standalone folder)

Some remarks:

1) You should run cmd and open folder where your selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar file located in my situation is C:\tools\selenium2.0\
2) for help also user this command -h